# cosine similarity pandas dataframe interpretation

Tags: python, pandas

```
import numpy as np; import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity


df_flask = pd.DataFrame([[100,152,70,80,2,10]],columns=['weight','height','wc','hc','sex','age'])

df_flask2 = pd.DataFrame([[55.6,154,92,27,1,70]],columns=['weight','height','wc','hc','sex','age'])

print (cosine_similarity(df_flask2.iloc[[0]],df_flask.iloc[[0]]))
```

i have this sample code to try to get the cosine similarity as my objective is get them most similar person, I want to know if this is applicable to use as a similarity metric? I have seen papers use pearson correlation and other algorithm for person-person comparison but I want to try and use cosine similarity if it applies.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but with potential problems.

As probably know the cosine similarity will compute the dot product between the two entries. Since the range of the values is not similar the components that reach higher values will dominate the result. In this case it will be height and weight. Compare that two sex (which reaches 2) and you'll see that sex will not matter much (unless everything else is the same).

This is probably not what you want. To make sure the similarity more uniform with respect to the different dimensions consider normalizing the values to be in similar ranges (say 0 to 1).

If you do want some features to matter more than other you can scale them up or down to get something that works for your application.

Comment: any suggestion that you can make for gender? i chose 1 for male and 2 for female.

Comment: @Dr.DOOM It would definitely be better if you use two dimensions (2 numbers) say 1,0 for male and 0,1 for female (the cosine similarity works better this way). The scale will still be problematic. If you don't want to rescale the other values down you can scale the gender values up (for example 150, 0 for male and 0, 150 for female).

Comment: How should I make my dataframe now? like this? df_flask = pd.DataFrame([[100,152,70,80,[ 150, 0],10]],columns=['weight','height','wc','hc','sex','age'])

Comment: [100,152,70,80, 150, 0,10]

Comment: would I have to add another column name for that?